# Повторное тображение уже загруженного анимированного WEBP-изображения с начала

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, webp

Имеется проблема: при изначальной загрузке анимированного webp-изображения на страницу все работает корректно. Изображение грузится и по окончании загрузки отображается с начала анимации. Анимация изображения зациклена, что означает ,что она продолжает по кругу проигрываться даже когда его скрываю со страницы (удаляется класс). Вставляется оно как фоновое изображение к элементу DIV. При необходимости снова отобразить анимацию я добавляю класс к диву, но анимация проигрывается не с начала, а с момента, в котором анимация находится с момента изначальной загрузки.
Манипуляции с DOM происходят посредством jQuery.

Рабочий вариант - добавлять в конец URL к изображению рандмного значения, но это означает его повторную загрузку, а анимированных изображений на странице много и весят они достаточно много (около мегабайта), что исключает применение данного способа для людей с медленным интернетом.

Уважаемые эксперты, подскажите, есть ли варианты сэмулировать в браузере загрузку уже загруженного изображения и проиграть анимацию именно с начала? Крайне желательно решить проблему не прибегая к грамоздким сторонним плагинам. В первую очередь хочется понять суть решения, а не подгрузить мегабайтный плагин и получить быстрый но непонятный результат.

Сейчас экспериментирую с конструкциями через объект изображения:

```
var img         = new Image();
let promise     = this.load_image('/images/' + image_url, img);

promise.then((res) => {
    this.loaded(); // отображаем изображение
});

load_image: async function(url, elem)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        elem.onload = () => resolve(elem);
        elem.onerror = reject;
        elem.src = url;
    });
},
```